# How would I create a Makefile that remotely updates itself?

Tags: unix, makefile

I have a makefile that I've changed up a bit here to look more generalized

```
.PHONY:
        bash hash.sh

all: .PHONY lab tests.zip

lab: .PHONY lab.cpp
        g++ -o lab lab.cpp -g -Wall -std=c++11

tests.zip:
        curl -L -O https://url/tests.zip
        unzip tests.zip

tests: .PHONY lab tests.zip
        bash scripts/test.bash lab.cpp

clean:
        rm -rf scripts tests bitset-tests.zip
```

I am a TA for an entry level computer science course at my university, and I've created a makefile here for my students to use to compile and test their code seamlessly.

One thing I want to do though is to have the makefile update itself every time the remote repository has a new version of it. I know I could just have them update the file themselves, but my job is to make the students focus less on setting things up and more on just coding for now, since it's entry level. So for the purposes of this, I'm sticking with the idea I have.

Currently, I'm achieving this with a script `hash.sh` which fetches a hash of the makefile from the repo, and compares it to a hash of the makefile in the student's directory. If the hashes don't match, then the updated makefile is fetched and replaces the old one. This is done in the `.PHONY` recipe. I should also mention that I don't want to add a recipe that updates it like `make update`, because again I want the process to be seamless. You'd be surprised how many students wouldn't utilize that feature, so I want to build it into the ones they will use for sure.

Is there a better method for this, or am I doing something wrong with this one?

Comment: This is an abuse of the special `.PHONY` target name. It is not meant to be used as a target with actual rules, or as a prerequisite of another target. It's just a marker target that marks its prerequisites as "always out of date regardless of file existence and time stamps".

Comment: Instead of `curl -L -O https://url/tests.zip`, it's better to use `curl -L -o $@ https://url/tests.zip` so that the filename in the URL can safely be changed without breaking your makefile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thomas has the right idea, but you can't use .PHONY here because it would means the makefile is ALWAYS out of date; `make` knows this so it doesn't re-exec itself if its included makefile is marked .PHONY.

You need to create a way for make to know if the makefile was changed since the last time it was run locally.  I recommend you do it like this:

```
<normal makefile here>

Makefile: FORCE
        curl https://.../Makefile -o Makefile.tmp
        cmp -s Makefile Makefile.tmp && rm -f Makefile.tmp || mv -f Makefile.tmp Makefile

FORCE:
```

What does this do?  First it uses [a `FORCE` target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Force-Targets.html) which is an old-school way to emulate a `.PHONY` target, which is always out of date, without actually using `.PHONY` (which as I mentioned above, is handled specially by GNU make in this situation).

Second it retrieves the `Makefile` but only updates the local makefile if it has changed.  If it hasn't changed, it doesn't update the local makefile and so make won't re-exec itself.

Comment: I haven't tested this yet, but it looks good! The only issue I see is that the makefile still uses the old version when it's replacing itself. Is there a way to force the makefile to restart, and not infinitely?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  After the download, if the makefile has been replaced, then make will see that its timestamp is updated and it will re-exec.  If the makefile is not replaced, then make will see that its timestamp is _not_ updated and will _not_ re-exec.

Comment: Oh okay. I was doing some testing yesterday, and it didn't appear the makefile had any concept of its own timestamp. Would you happen to know how that works by chance? It executes the target with `FORCE` as a prereq, completes it & updates the file -- how does it know to re-exec? Does it check its own timestamp after every rule execution?

Comment: Every makefile that is read in, either directly or through `include`, is considered as a goal target and make sees if it can be updated.  If any makefile is updated, then make re-execs itself.  Every time it re-execs itself, it starts all over again of course.  But the second time through, it should not be updated so it shouldn't re-exec again.  The `FORCE` thing is explained in the manual link I gave above.  Information on re-exec is here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Remaking-Makefiles.html

Answer (score 0):

The whole stuff with fetching a hash sounds overly complicated. If you're going to do a fetch anyway, why not unconditionally fetch the entire makefile? It saves a network round trip, which is probably the limiting factor; the actual data is probably just a few kB anyway.

If you're using `curl`, notice the `--time-cond` option, for example:

```
curl https://... --time-cond Makefile -o Makefile
```

This will only fetch and update the `Makefile` if it's newer than the mtime of the current file. It works by sending an `If-Modified-Since` HTTP header, so you'll need some cooperation from the server for this to work reliably.

If using GNU make, you can use another neat trick: [Remake the makefile itself](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Remaking-Makefiles). If you have a rule whose target is `Makefile`, it will be executed before anything else happens, and `make` will re-read the updated `Makefile` before proceeding:

```
.PHONY: Makefile
Makefile:
    curl https://... --time-cond Makefile -o Makefile
```

Note that this will lead to infinite loops if for whatever reason the `--time-cond` leads to an unconditional update, so it wouldn't hurt to guard against that:

```
.PHONY: Makefile
Makefile:
    [[ ! -v MAKE_RESTARTS ]] && \
        curl https://... --time-cond Makefile -o Makefile
```

Comment: I was going to use the `--time-cond` flag, but the students can download the file at any time, which would change the modification time to whenever they download it, and thus could be "outdated" even though the updated version contains the newer content.

Comment: Fair enough, there are plenty of reasons why it wouldn't work well, so you can just omit it. The rest of the answer still applies.

Comment: Testing myself, the `Makefile` target does not seem to do anything special. I've set it up to download the updated Makefile, it neither runs unconditionally nor restarts the make process. Using GNU Make 4.2.1

Comment: Ah, sorry, you need a `.PHONY: Makefile` rule. Otherwise, since the `Makefile` already exists and has no newer prerequisites (it has no prerequisites at all), it will be considered up to date and not be remade.